# 2018: a year in moderation

Tags: discussion, moderation, statistics

It's New Year's Day in [Stack Exchange land](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zulu_Time)...

A distinguishing characteristic of these sites is how they are moderated:

> We designed the Stack Exchange network engine to be mostly self-regulating, in that we amortize the overall moderation cost of the system across thousands of teeny-tiny slices of effort contributed by regular, everyday users.
> -- [A Theory of Moderation](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/)

While there certainly are [Moderators](https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/11/21/our-theory-of-moderation-re-visited/) here, a significant amount of the *moderation* is done by ordinary people, using the privileges
they've earned by virtue of their contributions to the site. Each of you contributes a little bit of time and effort, and together you accomplish much.

As we enter a new year, let's pause and reflect, taking a moment to appreciate the work that we do here together.
To that end, here is how the moderation done here on Electrical Engineering breaks down by activity over the past 12 months:

```
                 Action                  Moderators Community¹
---------------------------------------- ---------- ----------
Users suspended²                                 10         24
Users destroyed                                  97          0
Users deleted                                     4          0
Users contacted                                  35          0
User suspensions lifted early                     1          0
Tasks reviewed³: Suggested Edit queue           288      5,640
Tasks reviewed³: Reopen Vote queue              227      2,452
Tasks reviewed³: Low Quality Posts queue        299      3,540
Tasks reviewed³: Late Answer queue              141      2,643
Tasks reviewed³: First Post queue               238     14,259
Tasks reviewed³: Close Votes queue              518     15,391
Tags merged                                       7          0
Tag synonyms proposed                             4          4
Tag synonyms created                              5          1
Questions reopened                              110         15
Questions protected                              45        126
Questions migrated                              395         13
Questions merged                                 14          0
Questions flagged⁴                               11      3,066
Questions closed                              2,707      4,285
Question flags handled⁴                       1,048      2,029
Posts unlocked                                    0        100
Posts undeleted                                  60        472
Posts locked                                     25        583
Posts deleted⁵                                2,681     10,531
Posts bumped                                      0      8,729
Escalations to the CM team                        1          0
Comments undeleted                               76          0
Comments flagged                                  2      5,198
Comments deleted⁶                             5,116     12,963
Comment flags handled                         1,676      3,524
Bounties canceled                                 2          0
Answers flagged                                  60      7,601
Answer flags handled                          6,770        891
All comments on a post moved to chat             88          0
```

#### Footnotes

¹ "Community" here refers both to [the membership of Electrical Engineering](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/users) *without* [diamonds next to their names](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators), and to the automated systems otherwise known as [user #-1](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/users/-1).

² The system will suspend users under three circumstances: when a user is recreated after being previously suspended, when a user is recreated after being destroyed for spam or abuse, and when a network-wide suspension is in effect on an account.

³ This counts every review that was submitted (not skipped) - so the 3 suggested edits reviews needed to approve an edit would count as 3, the goal being to indicate the frequency of moderation actions. This also applies to flags, etc.

⁴ Includes close flags (but *not* close or reopen votes).

⁵ This ignores numerous deletions that happen automatically in response to some other action.

⁶ This includes comments deleted by their own authors (which also account for some number of handled comment flags).

Wishing you all a happy new year...

Comment: Was this an autogenerated template on multiple sites or hand crafted?