# 2019: a year in moderation

Tags: discussion, moderation, statistics

It's New Year's Day in [Stack Exchange land](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zulu_Time)...

A distinguishing characteristic of these sites is how they are moderated:

> We designed the Stack Exchange network engine to be mostly self-regulating, in that we amortize the overall moderation cost of the system across thousands of teeny-tiny slices of effort contributed by regular, everyday users.
>   -- [A Theory of Moderation](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/)

While there certainly are [Moderators](https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/11/21/our-theory-of-moderation-re-visited/) here, a significant amount of the *moderation* is done by ordinary people, using the privileges 
they've earned by virtue of their contributions to the site. Each of you contributes a little bit of time and effort, and together you accomplish much.

As we enter a new year, let's pause and reflect, taking a moment to appreciate the work that we do here together. 
And what could be more festive than a big pile of numbers? 
So here is a breakdown of moderation actions performed on Electrical Engineering over the past 12 months:

```
                  Action                  Moderators Community¹
----------------------------------------- ---------- ----------
Users suspended²                                  20         44
Users destroyed³                                  51          0
Users deleted                                      2          0
Users contacted                                   38          0
Tasks reviewed⁴: Suggested Edit queue            163      6,135
Tasks reviewed⁴: Reopen Vote queue                58      2,639
Tasks reviewed⁴: Low Quality Posts queue         122      2,638
Tasks reviewed⁴: Late Answer queue                73      2,028
Tasks reviewed⁴: First Post queue                 28     11,891
Tasks reviewed⁴: Close Votes queue               265     11,599
Tags merged                                        2          0
Tag synonyms proposed                              2         12
Tag synonyms created                              14          0
Revisions redacted                                 2          0
Questions reopened                               103         44
Questions protected                               33         93
Questions migrated                               238         14
Questions merged                                   7          0
Questions flagged⁵                                13      2,164
Questions closed                               2,708      3,469
Question flags handled⁵                          885      1,291
Posts unlocked                                     2         29
Posts undeleted                                   54        436
Posts locked                                      17        404
Posts deleted⁶                                 2,292     11,391
Posts bumped                                       0      8,615
Escalations to the Community Manager team          4          0
Comments undeleted                                58          0
Comments flagged                                   0      6,425
Comments deleted⁷                              6,343     15,203
Comment flags handled                          1,456      4,969
Answers flagged                                   47      6,470
Answer flags handled                           5,650        867
All comments on a post moved to chat             116          0
```

#### Footnotes

¹ "Community" here refers both to [the membership of Electrical Engineering](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/users) *without* [diamonds next to their names](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators), and to the automated systems otherwise known as [user #-1](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/users/-1).

² The system will suspend users under three circumstances: when a user is recreated after being previously suspended, when a user is recreated after being destroyed for spam or abuse, and when a network-wide suspension is in effect on an account.

³ A "destroyed" user is deleted along with all that they had posted: questions, answers, comments. [Generally used as an expedient way of getting rid of spam.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/88994/what-is-the-difference-between-a-deleted-user-and-a-destroyed-user)

⁴ This counts every review that was submitted (not skipped) - so the 2 suggested edits reviews needed to approve an edit would count as 2, the goal being to indicate the frequency of moderation actions. This also applies to flags, etc.

⁵ Includes close flags (but *not* close or reopen votes).

⁶ This ignores numerous deletions that happen automatically in response to some other action.

⁷ This includes comments deleted by their own authors (which also account for some number of handled comment flags).

#### Further reading:

- Wanna see how these numbers have changed over time? I posted a similar report here last year: [2018: a year in moderation](https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6851/2018-a-year-in-moderation)...
- You can also check out [this report on other sites](https://stackexchange.com/search?q=title%3A%222019%3A+a+year+in+moderation%22)
- Or peruse [detailed information on the number of questions closed and reopened across all sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/341507/2019-a-year-in-closing)

Wishing you all a happy new year...

Comment: Such an unhappy SE site!

Comment: It looks like PAR for the course when you have a very diverse skill of users on a common interest with opinions vs self-validated experiences vs Laws of Physics. Speaking of which https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12628/2019-a-year-in-moderation  There is no solution, but my idea is a better template of example questions with self-test questions like; is this question easy or extremely hard to summarize an answer on the web.  Are there specifications relevant? list them as a check list for acceptance criteria.  Does this take a book to answer properly?

Comment: Ultimately a better written questions  MAY  lead to better answers but happier user experiences requires a more psychological critique of miscommunication , respect and appreciation if we have a better understanding of who is writing and their backgrounds and level of  expectations. I agree if it is worth saying, it should be put in writing, but it's old technology and verbal talk forums like Paltalk's PC Tech,  might permit more congeniality and human appreciation with problem solving but the concept here is to respond in any time zone and attract enough readers to get ads.

Comment: What's everybody talking about??  We seem to average about 500 questions per week, which makes all moderation actions a relatively small percentage.  If anyone has any specific problems they'd like to point to, might be a good idea to point to them.

Comment: @ScottSeidman I was only talking about the two down votes here

Comment: Obviously, the downvotes are because this question absolutely shows no research effort :)

Comment: @Huisman you made me laugh, and that's hard to do before my morning coffee kicks in, and especially hard because still sad about what happened.